# Are there any companies other than "Mom's Robots" that makes robots?

Tags: futurama

Are there any companies other than "Mom's Robots" that makes robots? It seems that mom has overrides to control any robot at any time (as seen in "Mother's Day"). Is her company the exclusive maker of all the robots on earth, or are there any other companies that makes robots and are independent from Mom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you're looking for *companies* that have built robots, but there some robots that we can be pretty sure have not been built by MomCorp (since it's unlikely that Mom is old enough):

- Calculon was built around the year 2000, and changes his appearance regularly. He apparently is David Duchovny.
- Project Satan, a military project in 2019.
- The Robot Devil has existed since at least 2275 ("The Fairness in Hell Act of 2275" refers to him).
- Kwanzaa-bot says he's been giving out *What The Hell Is Kwanza?* (sic) since 2354.
- It's not clear what fraction of the robotic population this accounts for, but both the planet with rapidly evolving robots ("A Clockwork Origin") and Bender's son ("The Bots and the Bees") make it clear that some (many?) robots aren't made -- they're born.

Its canonicity is questionable, but the Futurama comic [Your Mother Wears Pilot Boots](http://theinfosphere.org/Your_Mother_Wears_Pilot_Boots) involves competitors of MomCorp. One of them is Dad from Dad's Dandy Doodads. Since MomCorp is in a lot of different industries (the eyePhone and Robot Oil, for example), they don't necessarily make robots, but the name of the company implies to me that they might. They're a big enough competitor to be attempting (and almost pulling off) a hostile takeover. ([Here's a transcript](http://www.futurama-madhouse.net/comics/comic_0050.shtml) of the comic.)

Comment: While I like your answer, I don't feel like it adequately answers the question, for a few reasons: 
1: It's not clear how canon the comic book is to the show.
2: While the Dad character makes sense in the furturama universe, he has never once been mentioned in the show.
3: It doesn't clearly say that Dad's Dandy Doodads makes robots. While we have evidence that Mom's company does.

Comment: I agree. I've added a list of a few robots almost definitely not built by MomCorp. It's not an answer either, but there it is.

Comment: MomCorp was originally founded to drill dark matter on Vergon 6 (as seen in Benders Game), and Mom's Friendly Robot Company was started to provide labor for the dark matter mines.

Comment: I think you're right that there are certainly some robots not made by Mom, but the OP is also right that Mom "has overrides to control any robot at any time" so how does she do that?